# python get opt long option only

Tags: python, getopt, getopt-long

I want to use getopt to get input from command line argument with long option only

Example: `./script --empid 123`

```
options, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],['empid='])
    for opt, arg in options:
        print 'opts',opt
        if opt in ('--empid'):
            emp_Id = arg
```

I am getting the error `getopt.GetoptError: option --empid not recognised` error with the above code. What might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you didn't read the documentation for [`getopt.getopt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt):

> getopt.getopt(args, options[, long_options])
>
> Parses command line options and parameter list. [...]
>
> `long_options`, if specified, must be a list of strings with the names of the long options which should be supported. The leading `--`
>   characters should not be included in the option name. Long options
>   which require an argument should be followed by an equal sign (`=`).
>   Optional arguments are not supported. **To accept only long options,
>   `options` should be an empty string.**

so you have to do:

```
options, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "", ['empid='])
```

---

Quoting from the documentation of `getopt`:

> Note
>
> The `getopt` module is a parser for command line options whose API is
>   designed to be familiar to users of the C `getopt()` function. Users
>   who are unfamiliar with the C `getopt()` function or who would like to
>   *write less code and get better help and error messages should consider using the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module instead.*

Example of usage of `argparse`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--empid', type=int)
parser.add_argument('positionals', nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.positionals, args.empid)
```

This module is *much* more flexible, advanced and, at the same time, easier to use than `getopt`.

Comment: `parser.add_argument('--empid')` - this is most important part. Icluding `--` Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`long_options` is the third parameter of [`getopt.getopt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html#getopt.getopt):

The first line should be:

```
options, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', ['empid='])
```